# Parameter markers in SQL Query

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm new here and with Python, and tried to experiment with the module pyodbc.
The goal of the script below is that I can add two values to the table weightdata.

The variables are:

1. A timestamp
2. The weight

I want to create a new row in the table weightdata with the input(). and execute a SQL query with the two variables.

Thanks in advance!

**Problem**
I get te following error, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

```
('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

I tried to search the answer on the internet, but didn't found the answer I'm looking for.

**Code**

```
def insertweight():
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    weight = input("What is your weight today?: ")
    date = datetime.now()
    timestamp = datetime.timestamp(date)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO weightdata VALUES (%s, %s)",timestamp, weight)
    
insertweight()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyODBC uses qmark placeholders ([docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executesql-parameters)).

```py
def insertweight():
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    weight = input("What is your weight today?: ")
    date = datetime.now()
    timestamp = datetime.timestamp(date)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO weightdata VALUES (?, ?)", timestamp, weight)
    
insertweight()
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the error, but it doesn't add the values in the table of the database :(

Comment: You need to commit changes if you want to persist them.

Comment: Yeah, that does the tric! Thanks again :) Unfortunately I'm not yet being able to give you a +1, but you deserve it :P.